# How to check a clicked button's second class?

Tags: jquery

If I have two button, one with an `apple` class and the other with an `apple` and and `orange` class:

```
<button class="apple"/>
<button class="apple orange"/>
```

In my button click event for an `apple` button, how can I tell if the clicked button also has an `orange` class?

```
$("button.apple").click(function(event) 
{
 var hasOrange = // ???
}
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery provides [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) just for this purpose:

```
$("button.apple").click(function(event) 
{
 var hasOrange = $(this).hasClass('orange');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) like this:

```
$('button.apple').click(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('orange')){
    // it has orange class too
  }
  else{
    // it does not have orange class
  }
});
```

You can make it a bit shorter:

```
$('button.apple').click(function(){
  var cls = $(this).hasClass('orange');
});
```

> Description: Determine whether any of
>   the matched elements are assigned the
>   given class.

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: +1, this a good answer and I don't know why it was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

[$(this).hasClass('orange')](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

Comment: +1, there is no reason this answer should be downvoted either. It's correct.